# Saving spinner data and displaying it further without asking again

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am really new to android so apologies if there are some really silly mistakes. Also I searched for many answers about this topic but didn't find the appropriate solution.

What I want to do is, accept input from user only once while logging in and then from the next time the app is started it should directly move to the next page without asking the spinner values again.

Here is the code until now -

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> br = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, branchEnt);
    br.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    branch.setAdapter(br);
    branch.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> yr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yearEnt);
    yr.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    year.setAdapter(yr);
    year.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailsActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("branch",String.valueOf(branch.getSelectedItem()));
            intent.putExtra("year",String.valueOf(year.getSelectedItem()));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Currently this code passes the selected values of the spinner but the activity reoccurs every time I start the app. And I don't want that to happen. The data should be saved once entered and not asked from the second time.

Comment: you need to save the data when the user logs in the first time, and then get the data back when logging again to check if it exists and proceed. Check @karthic answer, nice one; +1 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way in which you can save your data from spinner in SharedPreferences.
The following code will save values from spinner into shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("branch", String.valueOf(branch.getSelectedItem()));
editor.putString("year", String.valueOf(year.getSelectedItem()));
editor.commit();
```

To display the value from sharedpreferences on any other activity, simply do the following:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES",MODE_PRIVATE);
String branch = sharedpreferences.getString("branch","");
String year = sharedpreferences.getString("year","");
```

This will simply put your values in string branch and year which you can print anywhere by using setText. No need for any complicated stuff. Just use these 2 sets of code for saving and loading preferences respectively and you are done. Hope this helps you. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Use shared preferences to save the data, then on start up use an if statement to determine whether the user needs to fill it out.

Answer (score 1):

We have a concept called `shared preferences` in android where you can save data in your app which will be available across all the activities in your app. To create a shared preference file, copy the below code to your main class above `onCreate()` method like this :

```
public class AboutUsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);
}
}
```

This will create a shared preference file with the name `mypref`. Now you can populate the key values like below:

```
sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("branch", String.valueOf(branch.getSelectedItem()));
editor.putString("year", String.valueOf(year.getSelectedItem()));
editor.apply();
```

This will store `branch` and `year` variables in shared preference file 'mypref'

Now, everytime, your activity launches, you need to check if any value is stored for these variables in `mypref` file in the `onCreate()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

    sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
    String branch= sharedpreferences.getString("branch", "default value");
    String year= sharedpreferences.getString("year", "default value");
}
```

If `branch` and `year` contains any values, you can write your logic accordingly.

You can read more about shared preference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Hope this helps :)

**Edit 1 :**

On click listener for the button which will post the data in shared preference that will be available to next activity:

```
Button storeDataInSP = findViewById(R.id.back);
    storeDataInSP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("branch", String.valueOf(branch.getSelectedItem()));
            editor.putString("year", String.valueOf(year.getSelectedItem()));
            editor.apply();
        }
});
```

Add the above method in onCreate() of the activity where your button is located. Also make sure your spinners are also located in the same activity.

**Edit 2 :**
Your FirstActivity should look like this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This will open shared preference file and load variables "year" and "branch"
        sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
        String branchstring = sharedpreferences.getString("branch", "0");
        String yearstring = sharedpreferences.getString("year", "0");

        // This will check if the variables hold data. If so, it will send the control to Secondactivity
        if ((branchstring == "0") || (yearstring == "0"){

            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(aboutusintent);

        } else {

            // If those variables dont have values, your FirstActivity will load
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

        }

        // Here, you will get selected values from spinners and populate shared preference file.
        // Remember I didn't included the code to map spinners, which you need to do here. Otherwise "branch" and "year" will throw error.

        sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("branch", String.valueOf(branch.getSelectedItem())); // branch is the spinner
        editor.putString("year", String.valueOf(year.getSelectedItem())); // year is the spinner
        editor.apply();
}
```

}

Comment: I edited my code as said by you just replaced the "getActivity()" with 'this'. I am passing the strings 'branch' and 'year' as putExtra() through my intent to next activity. But yet the app is asking for spinner values when closed and opened again. How can this be solved?

Comment: you need to check the shared preference file in the onCreate() method of your activity. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Do I need to change the value of "default value" in the strings 'branch' and 'year' ??

Comment: if the respective value is not already stored in the variable, system will take `default value`. You dont need to change this for now. If you have any default branch and default year, you can put it here.

Comment: And by 'main class' in the first part of code you mean the current activity right?

Comment: can you please help me with the functions to be written in the onClickListener of the button by which I can send the data to the next activity through Intent.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. And yes main class means current activity.

Comment: I edited the code according to your edit although I had to write 'sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref",0);' instead of 'sharedpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);' but it is still not working. I mean the acitivty is not popping up and even after passing the values it is showing null as the output.

Comment: checkout my Edit 2

Comment: Why is there "0" corresponding to the branch and year in string? Because its giving me a null pointer exception for it and also the activity crashes and once the next activity is pulled up, it shows value 0,0 for both the spinners.

Comment: "0" is the default value for both the variables. Means, if there is no value found in shared pref file, system will assign "0" to both of those variables by default. You can put any value you want there as default. Can u pls attach logcat trace to debug the crash ?

Comment: I don't know about the error specifically I think it was because of some other statement. Anyways I figured out how it is to be done correctly. My application is working completely fine and as wanted. Thanks for your time and help.